Bridge rectifier vs full wave rectifier with two diodes
I've been wondering why bridge rectifier provides better significance and is mostly taught everywhere in universities rather than a similar circuit that uses two diodes in parallel instead of four.
Two-diode model of a full wave rectifier

Bridge rectifier

I observed the I/O and time domain characteristics (I am using the constant voltage model instead of the exponential model for simplicity of analysis), only to find that the output voltage of the bridge wave rectifier conducts after 2VD-ON (VD-ON = standard voltage necessary for diode to conduct) whereas in the two diode system it conducts right after VD-ON as only one diode is conducting in forward or reverse bias (similar to a half wave rectifier.) The image below shows the I/O characteristics of bridge rectifier in constant voltage model.

The time domain characteristics with constant sine signal input voltage is as below.

Though I know that in practical cases VD-ON is not significant, I'm confused why the bridge rectifier is more celebrated than the two diode version of the full wave rectifier.

That circuit you posted isn't a rectifier. Current runs in both directions through R.

In Bridge rectifier, current runs in both directions too through the load R, so we get positive half cycles everytime right?.

No, it only goes in one direction. That's what makes it a rectifier.

In your two-diode circuit across R is an AC voltage.

@Adiji007 Please quote the website from where you copied the image (not everyone might know that website, it is a good source of info). Also the diodes in your circuit are useless and more efficient without them.

@Adiji007 - Hi, As just commented, to comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each piece of that material. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) then [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). If the original source was a book or other offline material, [edit] the question & add a full citation e.g. title, author(s), page, edition etc. (see the linked rule for details). See [tour] & [help] for rules. TY

https://tinyurl.com/23cljmbg

The two-diode circuit in the first schematic is not a full wave rectifier circuit.

How about looking at what the load "sees."
Here's a standard bridge rectifier:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Here's the voltage across R1 to ground:

Here's your circuit:

simulate this circuit
Here are the voltages:

There's no point in your circuit where the voltage looks like the output of a bridge rectifier.
Your circuit is simply not a rectifier.  At best it could be considered a clipper.
